# Do you recognize this audio panel?

Tags: pulseaudio

Wondering if anyone recognizes the app in the images presented at the top of this question?

[Change PulseAudio Input/Output from Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65246/change-pulseaudio-input-output-from-shell)

I loaded Fedora 18 - MATE and don't see this app. Your assistance is appreciated.  If you are able to post the name of the app to the question, as well, that would be helpful to future users struggling with ASLA issues.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the PulseAudio (ie. not ALSA) volume control shipped by default with Ubuntu.