# Switching output sink/moving audio streams - but some apps still use the old sink!

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I'd like to easily switch between a usb-connected amplifier/dac and my onboard audio. I'm using a fully updated Arch Linux x64 with PulseAudio 4.0-2.

Another thread on this board is about switching the output sink and moving active audio streams, [see here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65246/change-pulseaudio-input-output-from-shell/67398#67398)

Using the accepted answer's script, albeit a little modified, I am able to switch back and forth between the amp/dac and my onboard audio, just as I would like. Equally as well, my audio streams are moved from the old sink to the new one.

The problem is that not every application uses the new sink. For example: If I have a YouTube clip paused in my web browser and I switch the output sink and move all the audio streams, if I then unpause the clip, the audio will still be played via the old sink!

It seems that moving audio streams is only about moving active - currently playing - audio streams. I thought that maybe audio streams that weren't playing was in some kind of suspended mode but still tracked by PulseAudio, and therefore movable, but it doesn't look that way. Probably for a reason, I don't really know since I'm not particulary familiar with how the sound system(s) work.

But if I instead of using *pactl* use the sound settings of *gnome-control-center* to switch sink, every single application honors the newly-switched-to sink - even my web browser with a paused YouTube clip.

**The question can probably be distilled to:** How can I, by using terminal programs like e.g. *pactl*, make every application use my new sink for playing sound, just like *gnome-control-center* does it? This includes programs that aren't currently playing some kind of sound, and therefore doesn't seem to have movable audio streams.

Comment: [A more concise version of the same question with an answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/520724/258991)