# How to send HDMI sound to OTHER HDMI port?

Tags: debian, audio, hdmi

I am running *XBMC* on a **Debian Testing** system on my **HTPC**. I want to switch between my monitor for browsing and my tv for *XBMC*. This is no problem.

But the sound only seems to reach my television when ONLY the television is connected. Otherwise my monitor will steal the sound like a seagull stealing bread from ducks.

HTPC:HDMI -> TV:HDMI = Sound on tv

HTPC:DVI -> TV:HDMI = No sound on tv

HTPC:HDMI -> Monitor:HDMI = Sound on monitor

HTPC:DVI -> Monitor:HDMI = No sound on monitor (not a typo, no sound when solo)

HTPC:HDMI -> Monitor:HDMI AND
HTPC:DVI -> TV:HDMI = Sound on monitor (what? On DVI?)

HTPC:HDMI -> TV:HDMI AND
HTPC:DVI -> Monitor:HDMI = Also sound on monitor only

It doesn't even seem to matter which screen I define as primary.

How can I have both connected, yet send the HDMI sound through the HDMI port?
I didn't even know the DVI port could transmit sound when HDMI-converter-plug is used.

Preferably I'd have a command line trick to switch the port where the audio is going. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62818/how-can-i-switch-between-different-audio-output-hardware-using-the-shell) has some interesting commands, but I cannot 'port' that to my situation. This HTPC also has DisplayPort, but I don't use that output.

The XBMC part of this question is irrelevant, you can immitate the problem using:
`speaker-test -D hdmi -c 2` (both my monitor and my TV have only 2 channels (stereo))