# Is it possible to play an audio file from a fedora 33 no gui server?

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, audio

So I'm using a old low spec pc as my home server. I've tried to play music by `sox` command. As you can see the output, the audio file playing but there is not output from my speakers. I've plugged in a speaker in the audio output port.

[image]

Comment: Please post `ps ax | grep pulseaudio | grep -v grep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the speakers are working otherwise, the problem could be connected to the audiodriver environment.However, you may need to set the AUDIODEV
try:
play m.mp3 -t alsa

Use "man play" to see about the other drivers options.

Also, look at these good pages

1- [How can I switch between different audio output hardware using the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62818/how-can-i-switch-between-different-audio-output-hardware-using-the-shell)

2-http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/sound_troubleshooting.htm

Comment: the problem was my pulseaudio daemon wasn't running.