# how to specify a specific sink and port for paplay?

Tags: linux, pulseaudio

I would like to use 'paplay' to play a sound on a specific port of a specific sink.
`paplay $FILE -device=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo` plays on my internal sound card, but that device has two ports (analog-output-speaker and analog-output-headphones) I would like to specify which port.  How do I do this?

Comment: Flawed workarounds: it's possible to [switch the entire output profile of the card](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62818/how-can-i-switch-between-different-audio-output-hardware-using-the-shell) or to load the `module-combine-sink` module to create a new sink that outputs to all ports on all sinks.  I don't currently see a way to output to a different port, which I'd like as well - I'll follow up here if I find one.